# Why do some of my ScalaTest tests using Mockito fail when I add a dependency on Specs2?

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest, specs2

I recently added a dependency on Specs2 to a project and noticed that some existing tests written with ScalaTest and Mockito failed. These tests passed again once Specs2 was removed. Why does this happen?

```
lazy val scalatestandspecscoexisting = Project(
  id = "scalatest-and-specs-coexisting",
  base = file("."),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++
    GraphPlugin.graphSettings ++
    Seq(
    name := "Scalatest-And-Specs-Coexisting",
    organization := "com.bifflabs",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.9.2",
//  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaTest, mockito)   //Tests Pass, no-specs2
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaTest, specs2, mockito)  //Tests Fail
  )
)
```

The tests that failed all used Mockito and all setup a mock method with two different parameters. One of the calls to the mock does not return value it was set up with. The example below fails. A further requirement was that type must be a Function1 (or have apply method).

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito.when

trait MockingBird {
  //Behavior only reproduces when input is Function1
  def sing(input: Set[String]): String
}

class MockSuite extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {

  val iWannaRock = Set("I wanna Rock")
  val rock = "Rock!"

  val wereNotGonnaTakeIt = Set("We're not gonna take it")
  val no = "No! We ain't gonna take it"

  test("A mock should match on parameter but isn't") {

    val mockMockingBird = mock[MockingBird]
    when(mockMockingBird.sing(iWannaRock)).thenReturn(rock)
    //Appears to return this whenever any Set is passed to sing
    when(mockMockingBird.sing(wereNotGonnaTakeIt)).thenReturn(no)

    // Succeeds because it was set up last
    assert(mockMockingBird.sing(wereNotGonnaTakeIt) === no)
    // Fails because the mock returns "No! We ain't gonna take it"
    assert(mockMockingBird.sing(iWannaRock) === rock)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 [info] MockSuite:
 [info] - A mock should match on parameter but isn't *** FAILED ***
 [info]   "[No! We ain't gonna take it]" did not equal "[Rock!]" (MockSuite.scala:38)
 [error] Failed: : Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
```

Comment: This may seem like a strange thing to want to do, so here is my explanation. I joined a team which had already been using ScalaTest for quite some time. I strongly prefer Specs2 due to the lack of type safety in ScalaTest assersions/matchers. I began adding Specs2 tests after getting the OK from my team, when I noticed that a few existing tests were failing in very strange ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - according to Eric's comment below, this is a bug in Specs2 ≤ 1.12.2. Should be fixed in 1.12.3.

It turns out that Specs2 redefines some of the behavior in Mockito in order to get by-name parameters to match.

[Eric answered my question](https://twitter.com/etorreborre/status/261329677120049152)

> "I don't like this, but that's the only way I found to match byname
>   parameters: http://bit.ly/UF9bVC . You might want that."

From the Specs2 documentation

> [**Byname**](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Byname)
>
> Byname parameters can be verified but this will not work if the specs2
>   jar is not put first on the classpath, before the mockito jar. Indeed
>   specs2 redefines a Mockito class for intercepting method calls so that
>   byname parameters are properly handled.

In order to get my tests to pass again, I did the opposite of what was suggested in the specs2 documentation and added Specs2 dependency *after* Mockito. I have not tried, but I would expect by-name parameter matching to fail.

```
lazy val scalatestandspecscoexisting = Project(
  id = "scalatest-and-specs-coexisting",
  base = file("."),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++
    GraphPlugin.graphSettings ++
    Seq(
    name := "Scalatest-And-Specs-Coexisting",
    organization := "com.bifflabs",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.9.2",
//  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaTest, mockito)   //Tests Pass
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaTest, mockito, specs2)  //Tests Pass
//  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaTest, specs2, mockito)  //Tests Fail
  )
)
```

My tests now pass

```
[info] MockSuite:
[info] - A mock should match on parameter but isn't
[info] Passed: : Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1, Skipped 0
```

Comment: It turns out that this is a specs2 bug which is related to the special case we make for matching parameters which passed with an implicit conversion. Those parameters become Function1 parameters and get a special treatment for equality. The trouble is, a Set is also  a Function1! As a result when you stubbed a method using a Set parameter, only the last value that was set was used, regardless of the parameter you specified. This is now fixed in the latest 1.12.3-SNAPSHOT.